# How to return extra dynamic column based on query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return extra dynamic column based on some query. Suppose i have a table named as Table_A having columns A,B,C

If i want to return extra column i will do as below

```
SELECT A,B,C,D=1
FROM Table_A
```

D is the extra column with 1 value. Is there any way to put query on D like:

Select  SELECT A,B,C,D = (//i want to put query which will return 1 or 0)
    FROM Table_A

Can i do this?

Comment: You can directly write a query instead of D =1

Comment: The best answer depends on specific details you haven't provided.  You might be able to use a CASE expression.  You might be able to use a query inline.  Maybe you need to join another table or use a subquery.  There aren't really enough details to answer your question more than "Yes, you can do it."  Post your query, a sample of your data, and your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah like this

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C,
       (SELECT somecol
        FROM   sometable
        ORDER  BY somecol
        limit 1) AS D
FROM   Table_A
```

**LIMIT:** To avoid `sub-query` returns more than one row if any

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.

```
SELECT A,B,C, (
   SELECT Some_Column FROM Some_Table) AS D
FROM Table_A
```

You can also use columns from Table_A in the subquery's where clause. 
Note that subquery's can lead to bad performance, as they go off for each result row.